# Bamboolib in Databricks

Tags: python, azure-databricks

I was looking to have a UI within databricks notebook use it to display data from a dataframe. I also wanted to edit the rows or insert new rows from the UI.

I tried bamboolib but the edit button looks disabled. Is there a way I can insert new rows and possibly edit existing ones from the UI itself ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- There is a conditional replace operation on bamboolib directly to update the Pandas dataframe values based on given condition.

[image]

- However, there is no separate operation to insert a new row to the Pandas dataframe. You can instead use Concatenate operation.
- To use this, we need to have a Pandas dataframe of records that we want to insert. If you want to have a UI base for insert as well, you can use the following code:

```
#my dataframe

import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import bamboolib as bam

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[[1,'a'],[2,'b']], schema=['id','nm'])
#df.show()

pdf = df.toPandas()
bam.show(pdf)
```

- I have used `ipywidgets` in the following way to create a text field and button to create a dataframe for records to be inserted (Note: Enter the records to be inserted as array of arrays as shown in the below image).

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

text_input = widgets.Text(description="Enter rows to insert as array of records:")
button = widgets.Button(description="INSERT")
output = widgets.Output()

display(text_input)
display(button, output)

def on_button_click(b):
    with output:
        global insert_df
        insert_df = pd.DataFrame(eval(text_input.value),columns=df.columns)  #df is the spark dataframe
        print("dataframe for records to be inserted is created")

button.on_click(on_button_click)
```

[image]

- Now, use `Concatenate` operation to combine the starting dataframe and insert dataframe vertically.

[image]

- After clicking *Execute*, the data will be inserted accordingly. The following is the output image for reference;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is such UI for edit existing/adding the new data inside the Databricks workspace.  To insert new data, or update existing data in the table you can use SQL commands, although that won't be so convenient as Excel-like UI.